# reactjs create-react-app bootstrap4 card not rendering correctly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm trying to use bootstrap4 with create-react-app. I realized bootstrap.min.css was missing so I put the following line in index.html in the public folder

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ"
crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I tried using a card and the colors were missing.

```
        <div className="card card-inverse card-primary mb-3 text-center">
            <div className="card-block">
                <blockquote className="card-blockquote">
                    React.js
                </blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>
```

If I then typed a letter in the  like

```
<head>s
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ"
crossorigin="anonymous">
```

The the card color would show. If I then remove the letter and hit save the color disappeared. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Actually i don't know what should i see  on page, but i can help you with live editor which uses create-react-app. I did same thing for you and get some nice view on screen [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/3279xxrlz6)

Comment: It's a rendering issue. I took the 2 outputs and compared them in a diff tool and the <head> section even rendered differently.. I'm not sure what happened

Comment: Is it necessary for you use bootstrap 4?? It is alpha version. Actually npm has bootstrap module with version 3.7 so you can easily use it with import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' in your index.js file. And if fourth version is necessary for you, you can download this css file to your folder and use it with import './bootstrap.min.css' in index.js file.

Comment: No it's not necessary to use this version. I am doing a proof of concept so I started using all the experimental stuff. I got it working in the end. I had never used bootstrap like this do I didn't use the actual reactstrap components and just regular divs and classes. Once I switched and did it properly it worked.